# Не срабатывает std::getline на первой итерации

Tags: c++, getline

```
int main() {
    int n;
    std::string s;
    std::deque<std::string> d;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        std::getline(std::cin, s);
        if (s.back() == 'p') d.push_front(s);
        else if (s.back() == 'm') d.push_back(s);
        s.clear();
    }
```

Как исправить?